# Calculate standdard deviation over time

Tags: sql, oracle

I have information about sales per day. For example:

```
Date       - Product - Amount 
01-07-2020 - A       - 10
01-03-2020 - A       - 20
01-02-2020 - B       - 10
```

Now I would like to know the average sales per day and the standard deviation for the last year. For average I can just count the number of entries per item, and then count 365-amount of entries and take that many 0's, but I wonder what the best way is to calculate the standard deviation while incorporating the 0's for the days there are not sales.

Comment: use `STDDEV` to calculate the standard deviation. here examples https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/stddev-stddev_pop-and-stddev_samp-analytic-functions

Comment: I found this too, but it does not include 0's on the days where I don't have any sales.

Comment: what do you mean by that ? stddev is analytical and groups records . can you provide an example in your question of what you mean by that ?

Comment: From what I understood you want to use data that is not present in your table. You need to artificially create it. What you would want to do is add a date,product and 0 amount for any missing dates.

Comment: the example you posted looks like monthly data no daily.

Comment: 2020 does not have 365 days in the year. It is a leap year so it has 366.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hierarchical (or recursive) query to generate daily dates for the year and then use a `PARTITION OUTER JOIN` to join it to your product data then you can find the average and standard deviation with the `AVG` and `STDDEV` aggregation functions and use `COALESCE` to fill in `NULL` values with zeroes:

```sql
WITH start_date ( dt ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL
),
calendar ( dt ) AS (
  SELECT dt + LEVEL - 1
  FROM   start_date
  CONNECT BY  dt + LEVEL - 1 < ADD_MONTHS( dt, 12 )
)
SELECT product,
       AVG( COALESCE( amount, 0 ) ) AS average_sales_per_day,
       STDDEV( COALESCE( amount, 0 ) ) AS stddev_sales_per_day
FROM   calendar c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT t.*
         FROM   test_data t
                INNER JOIN start_date s
                ON (
                  s.dt <= t."DATE"
                  AND t."DATE" < ADD_MONTHS( s.dt, 12 )
                )
       ) t
       PARTITION BY ( t.product )
       ON ( c.dt = t."DATE" )
GROUP BY product
```

So, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( "DATE", Product, Amount ) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-07-01', 'A', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-03-01', 'A', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-01', 'B', 10 FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> PRODUCT |                     AVERAGE_SALES_PER_DAY |                      STDDEV_SALES_PER_DAY
> :------ | ----------------------------------------: | ----------------------------------------:
> A       | .0819672131147540983606557377049180327869 |  1.16752986363678031669548047505759328696
> B       |  .027322404371584699453551912568306010929 | .5227083734893166933219264686616717636897
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5eb2706773cba63ee0cab093062e0d03)*